# html table and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can get the sum of a certain value in a table bay using this code..

```
 $(calculateSum);

 function calculateSum() {

 var sum = 0;
//iterate through each td based on class and add the values
 $(".d").each(function() {
    var value = $(this).text();
    //add only if the value is number
    if(!isNaN(value) && value.length!=0) {
        sum += parseFloat(value);
    }

 });
$('#result').text(sum);    
};
```

And my table
    
     
      
       Have Value
      
     
     
      
       12

Now,I have 5 tables in a html and each table has a td element which values differs from each other,Whats the best way to get those values in javascript?

Comment: do you want all td's values in one collection?

Comment: get the tables first, then use `.find` to get the inner `td`s

Comment: @Mritunjay Yes,and I want only specific td's that I want to get a values<td class="d"></td>

Comment: @Fabricator,can you show me some example on how to do that in javascript?

Comment: I want to get value in every table, I can do that by copying the javascript code in each table.So table 1 has value 12,table 2 has value 14.....What I mean is the javascript code is written in every table to get the value on each table.Is there's any better ways to write javascript code only once?Because those tables are in the same   template/html

Comment: Explain, by editing the question itself, what you actually want, and show some example of HTML code that you work on. Do you mean that you would want to compute the sum of all cells in class `d` in a table and then do something (what?) with the result? And do this for several tables? Using the same class name?

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over each `table`, and use `.find` to get descendant `td`s.

```
$('table').each(function(i, table) {
  var sum = 0;
  $(table).find('.d').each(function() {
    ..
  });
});
```